# How To Bind Two Chart Series To One SqlDataSource Object In ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, charts

I'm trying to create a line chart in Asp.Net with data from two tables (Incomings and Expenditures). Each table has a date and a cost (Inc Cost, IncDate, ExpCost and ExpDate). I'm able to create a line chart for either the incomings or either the of expenditures, but not both. I have tried creating a series but I'm not able to select both IncCost and ExpCost (I will show below)
Here is my SQL code

```
SELECT IncDate, SUM(IncCost),ExpDate, SUM(ExpCost) FROM Incomings, Expenditures GROUP BY IncDate, ExpDate
```

And here is what I'm trying to select for the data members. 
[image: When I change Series2 Data Members to ExpDate, the top data members changes to ExpDate as well]

The aim is to have the X values with IncDate and ExpDate (they are stored as dd/mm/yyyy format) and the Y value to have two different lines, one for IncCost and one for ExpCost.

Hopefully someone can see the problem. thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're referring to the fact that changing X and Y members for one `Series` also changes the other, a workaround is to switch from the Design view to the Code view (markup) and manually edit the desired data members for each `Series`.

Comment: ok brilliant thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS will change X Member and Y Member for both `Series` when using the GUI for the `SqlDataSource` configuration, which seems to be a glitch.

[image]

One workaround is to directly edit the markup:

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="400px" Width="600px">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="IncCost" ChartType="FastLine" XValueMember="IncDate" YValueMembers="IncCost" Legend="Legend1"></asp:Series>
            <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="ExpCost" ChartType="FastLine" XValueMember="ExpDate" YValueMembers="ExpCost" Legend="Legend1"></asp:Series>
        </Series>
    </asp:Chart>
```

[image]

Comment: Jstreet, for your lines, did you use data from two different tables? Mine is drawing now but the dates along the bottom are displaying randomly and some are miss/being displayed numerous times. I'm guessing I might need to join the two dates from the two tables in my sql but not sure how I would go about that

Comment: @Stuart no i used data from one single table. As long as you're correctly retrieving the data you expect from the database, that should have no effect on how it displays. It doesn't matter at this point if you used a join or not. Try executing the same query on SSMS, so you know exactly what data you should see on the chart.

Comment: Ok I will give it a go. Thank you